# Undefined reference to static method

Tags: c++, static-methods

This is probably something simple but I can't figure it out.

In my main.cpp I have:

```
Image image("/path/to/image.png");
int* h = ImageProcessor::dailyPrices(image);
```

And in my ImageProcessor.h I have:

```
//Maybe something is wrong with this? I am trying to forward declare.
namespace Magick
{
class Image;
}

class ImageProcessor {
public:
ImageProcessor();
virtual ~ImageProcessor();
static int* dailyPrices(const Magick::Image& abp_chart);
};
```

And in ImageProcessor.cpp I have

```
int* dailyPrices(const Image& abp_chart)
{
```

But upon attempt to compile I receive the following error in my main.cpp:

```
path/to/VendBot.cpp:17: undefined reference to `ImageProcessor::dailyPrices(Magick::Image const&)'
```

Comment: `int* ImageProcessor::dailyPrices(const Image& abp_chart)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to a function when linking with g++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043333/undefined-reference-to-a-function-when-linking-with-g)

Comment: Darn. Much more work to find duplicate than to answer. And no rep gain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the class name when defining the `dailyPrices` function:

```
int* ImageProcessor::dailyPrices(const Image& abp_chart)
//   ______________^ 
{
    // 
}
```

Comment: Yup everyone is 100% correct. D'oh! Will accept this answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `ImageProcessor::` to your method definition:

```
int* ImageProcessor::dailyPrices(const Image& abp_chart)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

dailyPrices needs to be in the ImageProcessor namespace:

```
int* ImageProcessor::dailyPrices(const Image& abp_chart)
```