# How to allocate 3D array in CPP using template

Tags: c++

I would like to write a template class for allocating 3D arrays for any type of variable. The following code is what I have tried:

```
class Alloc3D{
public:
    template <class T>
    static T*** Alloc(int w, int h, int d);
};

template <class T>
T*** Alloc(int w, int h, int d)
{
    T *** field = new T **[w+1];
    for( int i=0; i<w; i++ ) { 
        field[i] = new T*[h+1];
        for( int j=0; j<h; j++ ) { 
            field[i][j] = new T[d];
        }
        field[i][h] = NULL;
    }   
    field[w] = NULL;    
    return field;
}
```

However, when I call this function as:

```
int*** k = Alloc3D::Alloc<int>(nX_, nY_, nZ_);
```

it doesn't work.

My question is that can't I use this style to allocate 3D array for any type of variable? If I use just a function instead of class the template will work fine.

Comment: Your title has nothing to do with the question...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to static method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428049/undefined-reference-to-static-method)

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't allocate a big 1D array with `(w*h*d)` elements and then have some code to translate between (w, h, h) and linear coordinates? `int***` is really uncommon even in libraries that handle multi-dimensional structures.

Comment: An edit which invalidates the two previous correct answer... :-(

Comment: I’ve rolled back since your edit corrected the mistake that was causing the problem you were asking help for. Don’t do that pls.

Comment: -1 for the **multiple** edits which invalidate the answer.

Comment: @Insilico It may be a good solution. But why it's uncommon? Does this have something to do with access speed?

Comment: @Nevermoe: One reason is that it's less confusing. `int*` is easier to reason with than `int***` and it won't raise eyebrows. :-) Also, it allows you to control how the elements are laid out in memory, and for some algorithms it dramatically affects performance.

Comment: The edits of this post are under discussion [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267882/2982225)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the class name when defining the `Alloc` function:

Declaration:

```
template <class T>
static T*** Alloc(int w, int h, int d);
```

Definition:

```
template <class T>
T*** Alloc3D::Alloc(int w, int h, int d) {}
```

Comment: Sorry for the modification, but I think the essence of this problem is that if one can define a template class partially? e.g. only the member function is templated, not the whole class

Comment: Then you should post a different question. (If you didn't find any solution after googling for half an hour).

Answer (score 0):

It's because you only *declare* the `Alloc3d::Alloc` function. You define a *global* function `Alloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not the solution for your problem, I like to propose another implementation for what you like to do:

```
template<typename Ty>
class Grid3D
{
public:
    Grid3D(int w, int h, int d)
    : w_(w), h_(h), d_(d), p_(w*h), cells_(w*h*d)
    {
    }

    Ty& at(int x, int y, int z) { return cells_[p_*z + w_*y + x]; }
    const Ty& at(int x, int y, int z) const { return cells_[p_*z + w_*h + x]; }

private:
    typename std::vector<Ty> cells_;
    int w_, h_, d_, p_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Grid3D<float> g(4, 5, 6);
    g.at(2, 3, 4) = 3.14159f;
    // ...
}
```